# Split a torch tensor using a same-sized tensor of indices

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor, torch

Let's say that I have tensor

```
t = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
```

I want to split it using a same-sized tensor of indices that tells me for each element, in which split it should go.

```
indices = torch.tensor([0,1,1,0,2])
```

So that the final result is

```
splits
[tensor([1,4]), tensor([2,3]), tensor([5])]
```

Is there a neat way to do this in Pytorch?

EDIT : In general there will be more than 2 or 3 splits.

Answer (score 4):

One could do it using `argsort` for general case:

```
def mask_split(tensor, indices):
    sorter = torch.argsort(indices)
    _, counts = torch.unique(indices, return_counts=True)
    return torch.split(t[sorter], counts.tolist())


mask_split(t, indices)
```

Though it might be better to use @flawr answer if this is your real use case (also `list comprehension` might also be faster as it does not require sorting), something like this:

```
def mask_split(tensor, indices):
    unique = torch.unique(indices)
    return [tensor[indices == i] for i in unique]
```

Answer (score 2):

That is indeed possible using logical indexing, you just have to make sure that the index "mask" is made from boolean vales, so in your case

```
splits = t[indices > 0] , t[indices < 1]
```

or alternatively you can first cast your tensor `indices` to have boolean dtype.

Answer (score 1):

On top of other answers, for indexing in pytorch you can directly use index locations to access those elements:

```
t = torch.tensor([1,2,3,4])
print(t[[0,1,3]])
```

So you don't really need to store a tensor for indices. You can still store a numpy array with ones and zeros if you want, and then find access indices from that array:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
ind_ones = np.argwhere(a == 1).squeeze()
ind_zers = np.argwhere(a == 0).squeeze()
print(t[ind_ones])   # tensor([2, 3])
print(t[ind_zers])   # tensor([1, 4])
```